# Not able to place the table at center using align parameter

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table which will be loaded dynamically using jquery. I have give align parameter as center. But its aligned left. Please help me

```html
   <title></title>
<style>
.tb1 { background-color : #EEE8AA; color: black; font-size: 13pt; onfocus="this.value=" font:verdana}
.inp { border: 0; color: black; font-size: 13pt; onfocus="this.value=" font:verdana }
/* button styles */
.button0 { background-color: Orange  ; border: 110;  color: black; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block; border-color: #ff0000; }
.button1 { background-color: Orange  ; border: 110;  color: black; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 auto; display: block;  border-color: black;}
.button2 { background-color: Orange  ; border: 110;  color: black; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 auto; display: block;  border-color: black;}
/* web page layout styles */
html, body { margin: 0;}
div { height: 30%; background-color: white; float: left;}
#left { width:33%; margin-top:20px }
#center { width:33%; margin-top:20px }
#right { width:33%; margin-top:20px }
/* table-itemtable styles */
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td { text-align: center; padding: 8px;}
th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 300px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">
GRn:    <input type="text" id="grn" class="tb1" placeholder="Provide your input" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" autofocus="autofocus" /><br><br>
Unit:   <input type="text" list="combo-options" id="unit" class="tb1">
  <datalist id="combo-options">
     <option value="UNIT 1">UNIT 1</option>
    <option value="UNIT 2">UNIT 2</option>
  </datalist><br><br>
<input type="button" id="find" value="Find" class="button0"/><br><br>
</div>
<div id="center">
PO no:     <input type="text" id="pono" readonly="readonly" class="inp"/><br><br>
PO Date:   <input type="text" id="podt"   readonly="readonly" class="inp"/><br><br>
V.Inv.No    <input type="text" name="vinvno" readonly="readonly" id="vinvno" class="inp"/><br><br>
V.Inv.Date  <input type="text" name="vinvdt" readonly="readonly" id="vinvdt" class="inp"/><br><br>
</div>
<div id="right">
IRno:  <input type="text" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="inp" /><br><br>
Creation Date <input type="date" name="cdate" id="cdate" class="inp" value="<%= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new java.util.Date())%>"><br><br>
Type<select name="evalu" id="evalu">
 <option value="electrical">Electrical</option>
 <option value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center"> 
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Item code</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>  
        <th>Received qty</th>   
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
<div id="inspdiv">

</div>
</body>
</html>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align text in a table header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992096/align-text-in-a-table-header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to `width:100%;` in table.Remove that it works just fine.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/shubham_agr10/w0ss4vou/)**

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td { text-align: center; padding: 8px;}
th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 500px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center"> 
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Item code</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>  
        <th>Received qty</th>   
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Remove `float:left` from `div` in CSS.That is causing problem.Instead use `display:inline-block`

Comment: its because of my previous top layout html, body { margin: 0;}
div { height: 30%; background-color: white; float: left;}
#left { width:33%; margin-top:20px }
#center { width:33%; margin-top:20px }
#right { width:33%; margin-top:20px }. is there any solution for this

Comment: found the bug. its because of div { height: 30%; background-color: white; float: left;} . i removed the division in table. now it wotks! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px;}
th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 500px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center"> 
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Item code</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>  
        <th>Received qty</th>   
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Remove width: 100%; from table and it will be aligned to the center.

Comment: not working. i have added other of my css. is that because of anyother format ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add text-align: center; to th and td in CSS.

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */
table { border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}
th, td { text-align: left; padding: 8px; text-align:center;}
th {background-color: #4CAF50; color: white;}
tr {border-bottom: 1px solid;}
tbody { display: block; }
tbody {
    height: 500px;       /* Just for the demo          */
    overflow-y: auto;    /* Trigger vertical scroll    */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Hide the horizontal scroll */
}
```

```html
<div id="tablediv">
<table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable"> 
    <tr>
     <th> SLno</th>
        <th>Item name</th> 
        <th>Item code</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>  
        <th>Received qty</th>   
        <th>Accepted qty</th>   
        <th>Rejected qty</th>      
        <th>Remarks</th>             
    </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```